# XSLT : assigning values to global variable

Tags: xml, xslt

In xsl i Assign a variable named "CourseName" in the global scope.
Then I loop through each child nodes using

```
<xsl:for-each select="page">
```

then, how to assign the value for global variable "CourseName" (the global variable value should be from the loop, because i used that value in other conditions)

it is possible to assign declare the variable as global and assign through loop using XSL?

i used visual studio 2010

Thanks,
Yuvaraj

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is not a procedural programming language. Variables are not assignable, and for-each is a mapping expression, not an imperative loop. I would recommend reading about the language before trying to use it. You need a different approach to solve your problem; if you explain what transformation you are trying to perform, then we can help you code it.